# Animate self-sizing NSTableView row height

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nstableview

I have a project that uses self-sizing table view cells. I'd like to animate when the height of a cell changes. NSTableView's `noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged:)` will do this for view-based cells, but only when providing the height explicitly in the delegate's `tableView(_, heightOfRow:)` method. When cell height is calculated with auto layout, this value is ignored.

I can get the cell view itself to animate, but its containing row view jumps to the final size dictated by the constraints. Also tried using a height constraint on the row view and animating that, but it also was ignored. Anyone left developing Mac apps that has solved this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a sample project and put it on [Github](https://github.com/timtwotoes/AnimatedTableHeight), that animates the row height of a table. It does not use the delegates `tableView(_, heightOfRow:)` function. Take a look at it.

The necessary steps:

- Set the row height on the table view to use autolayout.
- Surround animation with a call to `beginUpdate()` and `endUpdate()`on  the table view.
- Change properties of the controls in your NSTableCellView and call
  `noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged:)` on the table within a call to `NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup`.

However it is easier if you just look at the code I put on [Github](https://github.com/timtwotoes/AnimatedTableHeight).

Comment: You've saved me again! I hate to admit that I had actually tried each of the individual elements that you've included, but hadn't stumbled on the right combination that you identified. My implementation involves hiding/unhiding arranged views in a stack view which works almost the same as yours. For anyone trying this, you just need to add a call to `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()` to what @TimTwoToes has done after setting the `isHidden` property. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm, even though, the tableview has its own time and animation curve, but that is less of a problem.